# What was the story behind the Wealth rain(dhan varsha) of Kuber?

Tags: ramayana, rama

When king Raghu(ancestor of Lord Rama) Asked for money from Kuber at that time Kuber did wealth rain for Raghu. I didn't know the full story. Is there any scripture reference to it?